# Satis Build Throws An Error - Cache Directory Not Empty

Tags: php, composer-php, satis

I'm currently trying to set-up satis to manage our internal packages using composer.

I have created my config.json file

```
{
"name": "Internal Packages",
"homepage": "http://packages.example.org",
"repositories": [
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "ssh://me@mypackages.com/Test-Component" }
],
"require-all": true
}
```

When I try and build it

```
php bin/satis build config.json web/
```

I get the following error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                    
rmdir(/home/lee.stone/.composer/cache): Directory not empty         

Warning: You have xdebug.scream enabled, the warning above may be   
a legitimately suppressed error that you were not supposed to see.
```

I have deleted that cache folder and tried to build again, but get the same error. Nothing has been created in my web directory either.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem so it will build succesfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the `xdebug.scream` option of your command line PHP version.

Explanation of that option:

> xdebug.scream
>    Type: boolean, Default value: 0, Introduced in Xdebug >= 2.1 
>   If this setting is 1, then Xdebug will disable the @ (shut-up) operator so that notices, warnings and errors are no longer hidden.

If the usage of `@` does not suppress the expected error when removing that directory in your installation, and that error triggers an exception that shouldn't exist in the first place.